# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c

I have just begun my programming journey. I code in the Ubuntu terminal. I am facing a problem while compiling a program where the `gets()` function is used.

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*example of multi char i/p function*/
void main()
{
    char loki[10];
    gets(loki);
    printf("puts(loki)");
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
warning: 'implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, run `man gets` in a terminal

Comment: The `gets` function has been removed from the standard library! (It was there in older versions but was declared 'dangerous' and subsequently removed.) You should use `fgets(loki, 10, stdin);` as 'suggested' by your compiler.

Comment: Litte tip for further programming: Be sure that your `main` function is of the return-type `int` and returns 0 on a successful exit :)

Comment: If you're following a book that uses `void main`, you should read the [C-FAQ 11.15](http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmainbooks.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Ubuntu, run `man gets` in a terminal. It should show you [this `gets(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html) man page.

That documentation states, in written English:

> **Never use this function.**

More generally, **before programming, read documentation.** For C on Linux,  consider reading [the man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/), this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), many C programming [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm), and the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

English wikipedia also [mentions `gets`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output#gets)

At last,

> warning: 'implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Seems quite clear to me, since written in English. As a rule of thumb, ensure that your program compiles without warnings. Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

You could be interested in understanding the acronyms [RTFM and STFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

I learned C and Unix programming (in 1985) by reading SunOS3 man pages (at that time on paper, at work, sold with the Sun3/160 workstation I had the privilege to use then), from section 1 to section 9.

You could read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) before the man pages.

---

> I have just begun my programming journey.

Then I recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html). In my grand-father's eyes, it is still the best introduction to programming, even in 2019. See also [these hints](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/guile-tutorial-1.html). It does not matter if SICP is using some programming language which is not very used in professional real life (but look into [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)): programming is about concepts, not about coding. The concepts you will learn with SICP surely will help you to write better C code later. Of course read http://norvig.com/21-days.html

---

NB. I am French (born in 1959) so not a native English speaker. But I was taught to read, including during my PhD studies, and of course during high school and by my own parents. And when I taught at university some CS stuff, the first thing I told to students is **read**. Never be ashamed of reading.

Answer (score 11):

`gets` was removed in C11, because it is [impossible to use correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). `gets` does not know how many characters it can store into the array and continues to write as many as the user provides, which leads to the program to have *undefined behaviour* - crashes, modification of unrelated data etc.

The fix is to use `fgets` instead, though keeping in mind that it leaves a newline in the buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// example of multi char i/p function
int main(void)
{
    char loki[10];
    fgets(loki, 10, stdin);

    // now loki will have the new line as the last character
    // if less than 9 characters were on the line

    // we can remove the extra with `strcspn`:
    loki[strcspn(loki, "\n")] = 0;

    // this will print the given string followed by an extra newline.
    puts(loki);
}
```